# Flash Builder Plugin/Feature: Collapse all function definitions?

Tags: plugins, actionscript, ide, flash-builder

Is there a way to quickly collapse all function definitions in the Flash Builder IDE? If not, are there any plugins that would let me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I had asked this question, but apparently there is a built-in way to do this. If you right click in the area to the left of the code where the line numbers are (or the gray area to the left of that), you can go to the menu option: Folding -> Collapse Functions. Unfortunately this doesn't work for MXML documents, just pure Actionscript ones.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't heard something to do that. If you can found write here please.
i wish Adobe can see some off xcode features for the next release.
i if you have passion you can check the link how you can collapse one by one.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fd7.html

Comment: Posted an answer. Doesn't let you do it everywhere, but its helpful for Actionscript at least.